# Strikethrough inTelerik Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

The html of Telerik grid is

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Strike</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

How to do strikethrough on the word Strike in cell `<td>`

I've tried

```
1. <td><strike>Strike</strike></td>
2. <td><span><strike>Strike</strike></span></td>
```

On front end
`<strike>` is coming as `&lt;strike&gt;`

Due to which it is not working. In code behind I've used HttpUtility.HtmlDecode/Encode. But none of them is working. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the query. We've handled it in javascript

Once complete view is loaded, we replaced the characters like this

```
$("#grid_id").html()=$("#grid_id").html().replace(&lt;/g,'<').replace(&gt;/g,'>')
```